# python super question

Tags: python

I have a syntax question about python's super() and multiple inheritance. Say I have class A and B, both of which have a method hello(). I have a class C that inherits from both A and B, in that order.

How do I call the hello() method of B explicitly from C? Seems simple enough, but I can't seem to find the syntax for it.

Answer (score 5):

To call `B`'s `hello` method explicitly from `C`:

```
B.hello(self,...)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> class A(object):
    def hello(self):
        print "hello from A"

>>> class B(object):
    def hello(self):
        print "hello from B"

>>> class C(A, B):
    def hello(self):
        print "hello from C"

>>> c = C()
>>> B.hello(c)
hello from B
>>> # alternately if you want to call it from the class method itself..
>>> class C(A, B):
    def hello(self):
        B.hello(self) # actually calling B

>>> c = C()
>>> c.hello()
hello from B
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using super()–instead of the hard-coded B.hello()–, as explained in [Python's super() considered super](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).  In this approach, C.hello() uses super() and automatically call A.hello(), which in turn uses super() and automatically calls B.hello(), with no hard-coding of class names.

Otherwise, B.hello() is indeed the normal way to do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Remember that Python calls superclass methods from right to left.

Comment: it does?  no it doesn't.  MRO is left to right wherever it is otherwise ambigious.